# Acceder con un spinner a una lista creada en Realm en Android Studio (Java)

Tags: java, android, spinner

Os cuento: tengo un formulario con realm a través del cual puedo registrar elementos. Pues bien, ahora me gustaría poder acceder a dicha lista de elementos registrados para que me los muestre en un spinner, pero no tengo ni idea de como podría hacerlo. A ver si me podéis echar una mano.

**Edito:**

He conseguido acceder a la lista con el siguiente código:

```
    package com.isaac.appet;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.isaac.appet.HomeFragment.HomeFragment;
import com.isaac.appet.HomeFragment.Pets;

import java.util.List;

import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmList;
import io.realm.RealmResults;

public class AlarmsFormActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner spPetLst;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarms_form);

        spPetLst = findViewById(R.id.spPetLst);

        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        RealmResults<Pets> realmResults = realm.where(Pets.class).findAll();
        List<Pets> documents = realm.copyFromRealm(realmResults);
        ArrayAdapter<Pets> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, documents);
        spPetLst.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
}
```

Pero me muestra el nombre del paquete, con numero y tal, y quiero que me muestre solamente el nombre del elemento que le asigné en dicho campo. ¿Como puedo hacer esto?

Muchas gracias.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El tercer parámetro del constructor de `ArrayAdaper` es `T[]`, esto para realizarle un `toString()` a cada objecto del array y por eso es que te muestra el paquete en vez del valor que deseas. Normalmente se envia un array de String al constructor por lo que veo que tienes 2 opciones.

1- Conviertes los valores que quieres mostrar a `String[]` utilizando el valor que represente cada elemento del spinner. Suponiendo que tienes una propiedad `name` en la clase `Pet`, podrias hacer esto:

```
String[] petsName = new String[documents .size()];
for(int i = 0; i <= documents .size(); i++){
   petsName[i] = documents.get(i).getName();
}

 ArrayAdapter<Pets> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, petsName);
        spPetLst.setAdapter(adapter);
```

2 - O sobreescribes el metodo `toString()` de la clase `Pet` para que asi en vez de imprimir la localización de la clase, imprima el nombre del `Pet`:

```
public class Pet
{
   //...

   @Override
   public string toString(){ return getName(); }
}
```

Comment: Al final lo conseguí haciendo algo parecido y me ha funcionado :) Te agradecería si te pasas por mi última pregunta que he abierto, antes de volverme loco jajaja